# Pivot without aggregate function in MSSQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

Here is a part of my MSSQL 2008 [ERROR CODE] table, which I want to transpose to following structure. I tried searching a workaround but could not find a solution to accomplish the task. Using Pivot I think is not feasible as I cannot use aggregate function. Can someone please help me to how to make this possible?

```
+----------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
| SKILL ID | SKILL |                     PARAMETER                     |
+----------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | 121   | STANDARD VERBIAGE & PROCEDURES                    |
|        1 | 121   | ISSUE IDENTIFICATION                              |
|        1 | 121   | CALL COURTESY                                     |
|        1 | 121   | ISSUE RESOLUTION                                  |
|        2 | BO    | COLLECTION PROCESS ADHERENCE                      |
|        2 | BO    | INTELLIGENCE PARAMETER                            |
|        3 | EM    | SOFT SKILLS                                       |
|        3 | EM    | PRODUCT KNOWLEDGE                                 |
|        3 | EM    | CALL CLOSING                                      |
|        3 | EM    | CALL  OPENING                                     |
|        4 | FLC   | RESOLUTION                                        |
|        4 | FLC   | NONE                                              |
|        5 | FTA   | OTHERS                                            |
|        5 | FTA   | HYGIENE FACTORS                                   |
|        5 | FTA   | ACCOUNT SCREEN                                    |
|        5 | FTA   |   ORDER , DOCUMENTATION AND CONFIGURATION         |
|        5 | FTA   | VALIDATION SCREEN                                 |
|        5 | FTA   | PARTY SCREEN                                      |
|        5 | FTA   | ORDER , DOCUMENTATION AND CONFIGURATION           |
|        6 | NCE   | COMPLIANCE                                        |
|        6 | NCE   | CRM                                               |
|        6 | NCE   | ACCOUNT LEVEL /INSTALLATION DETAILS CONFIRTMATION |
|        6 | NCE   | CONTENTS/BILL DETAILS                             |
|        6 | NCE   | SELFCARE                                          |
|        6 | NCE   | FEEDBACK/SATISFACTION                             |
|        6 | NCE   | OBJECTION RESOLUTION                              |
|        6 | NCE   | CUSTOMER HANDLING                                 |
|        6 | NCE   | RED ALERT                                         |
|        7 | RTO   | ZERO TOLERANCE                                    |
|        7 | RTO   | OVERALL IMPRESSION                                |
|        7 | RTO   | SUMMARY AND CLOSING                               |
|        7 | RTO   | PROCESS KNOWLEDGE                                 |
|        7 | RTO   | OPENING                                           |
|        8 | SHMNP | SKILL AREA                                        |
|        8 | SHMNP | CONVINCING SKILLS                                 |
+----------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

This is may expected output

```
+-------+--------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| SKILL |           PARAMETER1           |       PARAMETER2       |  PARAMETER3                                       |
+-------+--------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| 121   | STANDARD VERBIAGE & PROCEDURES | ISSUE IDENTIFICATION   | CALL COURTESY                                     |
| BO    | COLLECTION PROCESS ADHERENCE   | INTELLIGENCE PARAMETER | NULL                                              |
| EM    | SOFT SKILLS                    | PRODUCT KNOWLEDGE      | CALL CLOSING                                      |
| FLC   | RESOLUTION                     | NONE                   | NULL                                              |
| FTA   | OTHERS                         | HYGIENE FACTORS        | ACCOUNT SCREEN                                    |
| NCE   | COMPLIANCE                     | CRM                    | ACCOUNT LEVEL /INSTALLATION DETAILS CONFIRTMATION |
| RTO   | ZERO TOLERANCE                 | OVERALL IMPRESSION     | SUMMARY AND CLOSING                               |
| SHMNP | SKILL AREA                     | CONVINCING SKILLS      | NULL                                              |
+-------+--------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the PIVOT function to get the result, you will just have to use `row_number()` to help.

The base query for this will be:

```
select skill_id, skill, parameter,
  row_number() over(partition by skill, skill_id order by skill_id) rn
from yt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f921/2).  I use `row_number()` to apply a distinct value to each row within the `skill` and `skill_id`, you will then use this row number value as the column to PIVOT.

The full code with the PIVOT applied will be:

```
select skill_id, skill,[Parameter_1], [Parameter_2], [Parameter_3]
from 
(
  select skill_id, skill, parameter,
    'Parameter_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by skill, skill_id 
                                     order by skill_id) as varchar(10)) rn
  from yt
) d
pivot
(
  max(parameter)
  for rn in ([Parameter_1], [Parameter_2], [Parameter_3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f921/3).

In your case, it seems like you will have an unknown number of parameters for each skill.  If that is true, then you will want to use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('Parameter_'
                          +cast(row_number() over(partition by skill, skill_id 
                               order by skill_id) as varchar(10))) 
                    from yt
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT skill_id, skill,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select skill_id, skill, parameter,
                  ''Parameter_''+cast(row_number() over(partition by skill, skill_id 
                                   order by skill_id) as varchar(10)) rn
                from yt
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(parameter)
                for rn in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f921/4)