# SQL Convert resultset from list to grid

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, resultset

I have the following results set that is the result of two joined tables and I would like to re-orientate the results using a subquery. This is  an example of the current result set which is a dynamic number of records:

```
Forename    Surname    Subject      Result
Mercury     Freddie    English      C
Mercury     Freddie    Mathematics  D
Simon       Paul       English      E
Simon       Paul       Mathematics  F
Garfunkle   Art        English      A
Garfunkle   Art        Mathematics  B
```

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
Forename    Surname    English    Mathematics  
Mercury     Freddie    C          D
Simon       Paul       E          F
Garfunkle   Art        A          B
```

I've tried using a case statement to populate it, but this results in the following:

```
Forename    Surname    English    Mathematics  
Mercury     Freddie    NULL
Simon       Paul       NULL
Garfunkle   Art        NULL
Mercury     Freddie    C          NULL
Simon       Paul       E          NULL
Garfunkle   Art        A          NULL
```

Comment: add your code it will be faster to help you

Comment: I think the following is applicable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109958/pivot-without-aggregate-function-in-mssql-2008-r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE`, you just have to combine it with some aggregate function like `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
 Forename, Surname
 , MAX(CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'English' THEN Result END) AS English 
 , MAX(CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'Mathematics' THEN Result END) AS Mathematics 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Forename, Surname
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8be2c/1)**